# Facebook Profile Pic API - get someone's full photo

Tags: facebook

I know how to get someone's thumbnail via the Facebook API, but how do you get the person's full profile pic? What permissions are necessary to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `type=large` to the query string. For example https://graph.facebook.com/100/picture?type=large

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed that one +1

Answer (score 1):

The full profile picture can not be retrieved via the user's picture connection (https://UID/picture?type=large will only return a picture of about 200x200).

To get the largest version of the profile picture stored on Facebook, you need to access the user's profile photo album. This requires user_photos permission.

The full profile picture can be retrieved by iterating over the albums, looking for the album which has the the type 'profile' and then getting its cover page:

```
public function getProfilePictureMaxUrl($facebook,$uid,$userAccessToken) {
    $params = array('access_token' => $userAccessToken);
    $r = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/albums',$params);

    foreach ($r['data'] as $album) {
        if ($album['type'] == 'profile') {

            //retrieve information about this album
            $r = $facebook->api('/'.$album['id'],$params);

            $pid = ($r['cover_photo']);

            //retrieve information about this photo
            $r = $facebook->api('/'.$pid,$params);

            return $r['source'];
        }
    }

    //Profile folder not found (could be because of paging)
    error_log('Failed to retrieve profile folder for uid '.$uid);
    return false; 
}
```